# How to Create a Socket Thread for Multiple BitTorrent Connections

Tags: java

I'm working on a BitTorrent Client and I need to setup a TCP connection for each peer. I read online that you can't set up a second active socket untill the first is closed, with a client socket.

Would setting up a multithreading server work just as well for managing each separate concretion?

I just need to read and write byte packets following the protocol to each IP/Port pair. Preferably in separate threads so multiple blocks can be downloaded across multiple torrents at the same time.

Whats the best way to approach this?

Comment: Where did you see that you can't have multiple sockets in java? I don't think that is true

Comment: I read it in a tutorial somewhere, can't find it now. 
So I could just place each client socket in a thread and run them concurrently?